# How can I link to a specific html file in a subdirectory on github pages

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I have a public Github repo which is published as a Github page. In the main folder I have an index.html file from which I try to link to other html files located in sub directories of that repo.

My Github page works fine:

`myname.github.io`

the index.html located in the *myproject* repo also shows up just fine:

`myname.github./myproject/`

From that *myproject/index.html* file I link to an html file in a subdirectory in that project repo:

`<a href="https://myname.github.io/myproject/subdir/example.html">link</a>`

But this throws a 404 page not found.
Any ideas how I could get this to work?

Best,
Jonas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932048/linking-to-another-html-page-on-github

Comment: @SteveTomlin, I've seen that post and I have done it like that. However, in that example the link refers to another file in the root of that repo while I link to a file in a sub directory. I was wondering if that perhaps makes a difference.

Comment: It also says "For navigating folders like /css or /js, make sure the folder is under the root."

Comment: Please share a [mcve] of your code and directory structure.